# Add listener to JPanel

Tags: java, jpanel, listener

I have a custom class CustomField that extends JPanel. As I often have to reuse the same pattern, my custom class is made of 2 JLabels and 2 JComboBox.
It's quite simple; the first JComboBox has ON/OFF choices and the second JComboBox is only visible if the first is set to "ON". I can manage this part.
The part that I however don't know who to design it well is that CustomField instances are in another class that is the main JFrame and in this JFrame, some parts will be visible only if the JComboBox from the CustomField class is set to "ON". I thought about using a MouseAdapter, but I don't know it is good practice.

Here is my CustomField class:

```
public class CustomField extends JPanel {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    JLabel text, portText;
    JComboBox<String> testCB, option;

    public CustomField(String text, String opt, String tst) {
        this.text = new JLabel(text);

        String[] onOffOpt= {"OFF", "ON"};
        this.option = new JComboBox<String>(onOffOpt);
        this.option.setSelectedItem(opt);
        this.option.addItemListener(new ItemListener(){
            @Override
            public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent ie) {
                portText.setVisible(option.getSelectedIndex() == 1);
                testCB.setVisible(option.getSelectedIndex() == 1);
            }
        });

        this.portText = new JLabel("Test:");

        String[] testChoices = {"Test", "Test2"};
        this.testCB = new JComboBox<String>(testChoices);
        this.testCB.setSelectedItem(tst);

        this.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        add(this.text);
        add(this.option);
        add(this.portText);
        add(this.testCB);
    }
}
```

And here is the main JFrame:

```
public class Main {
    CustomField cf = new CustomField("test", "ON, "Test2");
    public static void main(String s[]) {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Application");

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());


        panel.add(cf);

        JLabel labelTest = new JLabel("Label that should be visible or not");
        panel.add(labelTest);

        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setSize(300, 300);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

Basically, I want that the labelTest visibily changes according to the CustomField settings. In the way that it is made, I can not put the labelTest in the CustomField class.

Is there a clean way to do what I want? Should I redesign the actual thing and put all the fields in the same class?

Thanks!

Comment: Implement a `ChaneListener` or `ActionListener` that can notify interested parties that the state of your custom component has changed

Comment: "The first JComboBox has ON/OFF choices "  Why not use a JToggleButton?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you want to expose the combobox's state with a method in CustomField:

```
public boolean isOn() {
    return testCB.getSelectedIndex() == 1;
}
```

You can get an idea for how listening for state is done by looking at the method signatures in the documentation for various Swing components, which use the standard JavaBean listener pattern:  You’ll want to add three public methods, and one protected method:

```
public void addChangeListener(ChangeListener listener) {
    listenerList.add(ChangeListener.class, listener);
}

public void removeChangeListener(ChangeListener listener) {
    listenerList.remove(ChangeListener.class, listener);
}

public ChangeListener[] getChangeListeners() {
    return listenerList.getListeners(ChangeListener.class);
}

protected void fireChangeListeners() {
    ChangeEvent event = new ChangeEvent(this);
    for (ChangeListener listener : getChangeListeners()) {
        listener.stateChanged(event);
    }
}
```

(The listenerList field is inherited from JComponent.)

Now, you can simply add a call to `fireChangeListeners();` whenever you detect that the user has changed the value of the On/Off combobox—that is, you’ll want to call it in your ItemListener.

As you can probably guess, your Main class can now call `cf.addChangeListener`, and inside that listener adjust the visibility of your label based on the value returned by `cf.isOn()`.

You can learn a lot more by reading [these](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/package-summary.html).